# How to use listByBlog at Blogger API v3 properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, blogger, google-blogger-api

I'm in Node.js
I'm tryting to use listByBlog to get all comments without going to each posts from a blog.
But I really can't make it work.
I did "Try this API" on https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/comments/listByBlog
I'm getting 404 erros.

But it also doesn't work.
Please show me some examples.

Comment: Could you show some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

An undocumented feature of `listByBlog` is that it only works with OAuth, not just an api key.

Its easier to use the Blogger v2 api for this which does not require OAuth. NB: Blogger v2 API does not support CORS, so, from a webpage, as  you have to use "jsonp" callbacks.